# C# FtpWebRequest fails

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

This code fails. Any help please. Thanks

```
using System.net
using System.IO

string uri = "https://xyzabc.com//Mats//";
FtpWebRequest reqFTP;

// Create FtpWebRequest object from the Uri provided
reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));
```

Comment: Are you sure you are writing C#? AFAIK `import` is not a correct syntax in C#

Comment: im sorry, import is how you include files in C# equivalent to #include in C++

Answer (score 1):

Took it from the Msdn FtpWebRequestClass information:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

This is their solution

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
```

Their is also more information on the site about the properties and method of the FtpWebRequest class, also there are some examples of how it works.

Like rexcfnghk import isnt c# syntax, it should be `using`

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, because FtpWebRequest doesn't have a method called `Create`

```
(FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));
```

Try it with `WebRequest`:

```
(FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));
```